# Spring - error downloading small file < 1 kb

Tags: java, angular, spring, amazon-s3

I have created a rest endpoint where I provide a filename and the service gets that file from S3 and downloads it to the user.
It works fine for almost all files.

When we try to  download a file < 1kb it does not download and chrome shows error: "Failed - no file"

there are no errors on the backend server nor on Client side.
The client is written in Angular.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Path("/downloadCsvFile")
public void downloadCsvFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response,
    @QueryParam("fileName") final String fileName) {


    response.setContentType("application/csv");
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName);
    response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "Chunked");
    response.setHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
    try {
        final InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(AwsS3Utils.getObject().getFileStram(fileName));

        // Copy bytes from source to destination(outputstream in this example), closes
        // both streams.
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        LOG.info("Downloading CSV file");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception occured while downloading csv file for admin report", e);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the extension of file -  fileName - in case when size is less than 1kb ?

Comment: fileName=xyz_2019-06-23-to-2019-12-23.1577083634871.csv

Answer (score 0):

If the extension is unknown to the client it shows `"Failed - no file"` error.

Please check your extension. It should be known to the client after `'.'` like .txt,.csv etc

Comment: I tried with xyz_2019-06-23-to-2019-12-23.1577083634871.csv as well as xyz_2019-06-23-to-2019-12-23.1577083634871.txt   getting the same issue

Comment: But it might be considering .1577083634871.txt as an extension. Can you try with removing 1577083634871 and only keeping .txt

Comment: after your comment tried the same 
xyz_2019-06-23-to-2019-12-23.csv &
xyz_2019-06-23-to-2019-12-23.txt but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

solved.

the problem was with FileCopyUtils.copy method.
skipped the part of copying stream from one another.

new code:

```
final InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(AwsS3Utils.getObject().getFileStram(fileName)); 
final ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(inputStream); 
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName); response.header("Content-Type", "application/csv"); 
return response.build();
```